# Receive error msg: the parameter is incorrect

Tags: mount, unmount

i receive this error msg when i use this batch file to mount and unmount a drive in windows 10.

**mounting:**

```
@echo off

REM Be sure to change this to the drive letter you want to mount the drive to!
set drive=E

REM Be sure to change this to the Volume Name of the drive you want to mount!
set volume=\\?\Volume{52ade1a4-0fd4-44cd-aa69-bfda739bb9e6}\
set volume=\\?\Volume{4d654d26-f65d-4c67-b83c-876de0d6820b}\
set volume=\\?\Volume{59cc5e85-9403-425f-bd28-c22ed4e8ab8d}\
set volume=\\?\Volume{52fdf924-f0fb-4ba7-99e0-096a9c9d124a}\

:start
echo Mounting Drive...
mountvol %drive%: %volume%
echo Drive Mounted!

pause
exit
```

**unmount**:

```
@echo off

REM Be sure to change this to the drive you want to unmount! 
set drive=E:

echo Unmounting Drive...
mountvol %drive% /p
echo Drive Unmounted!

pause
exit
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Show a session with the error message. Take off the `@echo off` so the error will be visible.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>mountvol %drive%: %volume%
The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[mountvol](https://ss64.com/nt/mountvol.html)
syntax is:

```
mountvol [drive:]path VolumeName
```

The command should look like:

```
mountvol %drive%:\myfolder %volume%
```

You could try the following, but it risks failure because Windows doesn't like
files on the root of the disk:

```
mountvol %drive%:\ %volume%
```

Verify also that `%drive%` and `%volume%` have the correct values when running.

Comment: We are on a good track!! made it work removing all the others drives in the list, left only the one I want to mount. Used this line: mountvol %drive%:\ %volume%. Will try to add all other drives now.